# Text changed event of text box in a gridview

Tags: wpf, gridview, textbox, textchanged

I am new in wpf, so i have a problem in my gridview.

I'm using a TextBox in the GridView . Basically, what I want to do is call a method every time the text in the box is edited. That is when the text is entered, the function will call. That is the text change event should work.

Comment: whatever you're trying to do, use DataBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TextChanged` event.

.xaml:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" ... />
```

.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    // call your function
}
```

Comment: my text box is in the gridview.So how can i get the current value of this textbox?

Comment: Then, you'll need to modify the cell template so you can set the event. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4725474/3042204

Comment: i do the same, but how can i get the value in that text box?

Comment: @JineshG check the edit, you just need to cast the `sender` to `TextBox` and get the text