# Binding ListView field to a nested list WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I've the following classes:

```
class Event {
int eserc {get;set;}
int type {get;set;}
}

class Sequence {
List<Event> events;
int freq {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, I have a list of events inside a Sequence. I have a list of Sequence.
I want to show a **ListView** with a **GridView** with the list of sequences. For each sequence I want to have 2 columns, one with the value of the property *freq* and the other one should have the list of events associated with that sequence. For example: [image]
where the first line is related to the first sequence. The color of the rectangle represents the event's type. In the first sequence there are the following events:

- eserc 1 of type "red"
- eserc 2 of type "red"
- eserc 3 of type "green"
- eserc 4 of type "red"

---

I know that I have to do the binding to display values, but I don't know how to do it for the sequences, because I should bind the value of the column to the values of the **Event** objects within each single **Sequence**.
That's the code that I wrote for the **ListView**:

```
<ListView Name="resultsList" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence" Width="450"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding events}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Frequence" 
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding freq}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Of course, *Binding events* is wrong because that would work only if it was a string, but that's the idea. 

I searched on internet and I think that I should use something like **DataTemplate**, but I'm not sure about that and I didn't understand well how that works. I understood that it works when the source is an object, but in this case it's a **List** of objects and I don't know how to get the information.

Comment: Use a DataTemplate to show your nested list in the cells of the first column (Read documentation for [GridViewColumn.CellTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), and for an example using CellTemplate property, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725352/wpf-listview-with-gridviewcolumn-and-datatemplate)

Comment: Oh, and the coloring you can realize with a DataTrigger changing color depending on the value of the property the DataTrigger is bound to (http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/)

Comment: Lastly, +1 for the excellent presentation of your question, including a doodle to make it so easy to understand what your goal is. Wish people would more upvote well-formed questions than just only downvote badly written low-effort questions.

Comment: I just remember that i forgot to add one thing: "_I understood that it works when the source is an object, but in this case it's a List of objects and I don't know how to get the information._". Oh, you already know. See, you already know how to show a List<Sequence>: with a ListBox/ListView. So, then, how would you show your List<Event> in the column cell? Yup, you guessed it; again, with a ListBox/ListView... ;-)

Comment: how many items can contains the `events`?

Comment: Thank you @elgonzo! I'm trying to implement what you suggest, but with many issues.. I think I understood the main idea, but the implementation seems hard to do to me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that you need to define another list inside the first `GridViewColumn`, the list should be horizontal (Edit the `ItemsPanelTemplate`). You could either a `ListView`, `ListBox` or an `ItemsControl` (looks like the most appropriate).

To draw a `Border` with the different colors based on the `Event`'s type, you should first, define a custom `DataTemplate` for the `ItemsControl` items, and use a `DataTrigger` to set the color, here the full xaml to do that:

```
<ListView Name="ResultsList" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding SequenceCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence" Width="450" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                               </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border>
                                            <Border.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="red">
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="green">
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Border.Style>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Eserc, StringFormat='{}{0} '}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Frequence" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Freq}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The SequenceCollection:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Sequence> _sequenceCollection =new ObservableCollection<Sequence>()
    {
        new Sequence(){Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>()
        {
            new Event(){Eserc=1, Type = "red"},
            new Event(){Eserc=2, Type = "red"},
            new Event(){Eserc=3, Type = "green"},
            new Event(){Eserc=4, Type = "red"},
        },Freq = 3}
    };
    public ObservableCollection<Sequence> SequenceCollection
    {
        get { return _sequenceCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _sequenceCollection)) return;
            _sequenceCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And here are you classes with the needed adjacements:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Eserc { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Sequence
{
    public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public int Freq { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image: shot]

**On the side:**

1. make sure to define public properties to be able to bind them correctly
2. use the naming convention
3. use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` (they implement `ICollectionChanged` which is handy for change notifications)
4. don't forget to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your answer! I tried to implement it, but I had some problems.. First of all, it gives me an error on the definition of the SequenceCollection property, saying that "the type of property 'ObservableCollection<Sequence> is less accessible than property "Results.SequenceCollection" (Where Results is the class of the window containing the SequenceCollection).

Comment: Another thing, implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the OnPropertyChanged() method what I have to do? (I did it in the Results class)

Comment: Regarding the first problem, just make sure that the property is public. And for the notification change, whenever you want that changes on the property reflects on the ui, call  onepropertychanged() in the property.

Comment: Thank you @Usama, for the property the problem was that classes Event and Sequence were not public. For the INotifyPropertyChanged instead I can figure out how to do that, I think that's why results don't appear. I followed this tutorial http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/, implemententing that interface for Sequence and Event class.

Comment: Good :)), pls accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: It was useful, but I wasn't able to make it run :( it was exactly what I want but the sequence does not appear! Can you post the .cs code of the whole window which contains the SequenceCollection property? Because for sure I'm doing some stupid mistakes. Thanks!!

Comment: Will do, once I am out of the train

Comment: Thank you so much! When you have time to do it of course :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! With the whole code I solved the problem!! Thank you for your pacience :)

Comment: This is the most helpful answer with full functioning source code. Very nice. +1