# C# WPF columns' alignment inside a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment

In my application I have a `ListView` where I defined its `ItemTemplate` as follows:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParameterIconSize" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParameterDescriptionSize" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParameterValueSize" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    MaxHeight="50"
                    Margin="5"
                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                    Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Parameter.NameKey}" />
                <TextBox
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Parameter.Value}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Such code produces this output:

[image: Output from the code]

As you can see, nearly every column has a different width, whilst I wanted to make them even. I thought that going with `SharedSizeGroup` was the right way, but clearly there is something I am missing...

(PS: I had to set the maxHeight in the Image element because if not this would show:

[image: the yellow one is a 50x50pixel bitmap, the question mark a 120x120 bitmap]

)

I would like to have all three columns the same size, determined by these criteria:

- column 0: largest image
- column 1: largest textbox text
- column 2: fill the remainig space (as this is also a user input field, and I cannot know a priori if that input will be something like 0 or 1438233482379472 )

EDIT 2:
I forgot to specify that I want the textboxes in column 2 to be the same size, filling the available space.

Comment: if you want columns, use `<ListView.View><GridView><GridViewColumn  ...` - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725474/1506454)

Comment: Thank you, but that still isn't what I need. I don't want to hardcode a column width, and if I set it on Auto then the middle description ("Parameter_abcd") will be cropped, and the textboxes will still have different dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable the `SharedSize` functionality in the parent element.

```
<ListView Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```